# Display WMS Layer With Geoserver and Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to display a WMS layer from geoserver to my Vue.Js application. I am using Vuelayers (Leaflet) for the map rendering.

This is my code:

```
   <template>
  <div>
    <div style="height: 15%; overflow: auto;">
      <h3>WMS Layers with Layer selector</h3>
      <p>
        <b>NOTE:</b> Use layer symbol on the top right to select which layer you
        want to display. More information about WMS (Web Map Service) can be
        found on the
        <a
          href="http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html"
        >leaflet.js WMS example page</a>.
      </p>
    </div>
    <l-map
      :zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      style="height: 100%"
    >
      <l-control-layers />
      <l-wms-tile-layer
        v-for="layer in layers"
        :key="layer.name"
        :base-url="baseUrl"
        :layers="layer.layers"
        :visible="layer.visible"
        :name="layer.name"
        layer-type="base"
      />
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { LMap, LWMSTileLayer, LControlLayers } from "vue2-leaflet";
export default {
  name: "WmsLayers",
  components: {
    LMap,
    "l-wms-tile-layer": LWMSTileLayer,
    LControlLayers
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 4,
      center: [49, 12],
      url: "http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      baseUrl: "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/cite/wms",
      layers: [
        {
          name: "Boundaries",
          visible: true,
          layers: "cite:vnm_polbnda_adm3_2014_pdc"
        },
        {
          name: "Countries",
          visible: false,
          layers: "cite:transacthcmgis_salesaggregated"
        },
        {
          name: "Boundaries and Countries",
          visible: false,
          layers:
            "ne:ne_10m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

I don't have any error codes and nothing it's displaying in my browser. The integration is bit different in vue.js and I'm a bit confused. Any clues where might be my mistake?

My link layer: http://localhost:8081/geoserver/cite/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=cite%3Avnm_polbnda_adm3_2014_pdc&bbox=102.144027709961%2C8.4089241027832%2C109.471290588379%2C23.3922080993652&width=375&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=application/openlayers

This is the my developer screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your reference points to Leaflet code.

Comment: @TomazicM I confused my codes when posting my question. This is the right code which like the example you send me.

Comment: What do you see in browser debugger network requests? What goes to server and what comes back?

Comment: I add a screenshot. I am not sure if the localhost it's fetching anything, but still the map would display even if my geoserver links are not good.

Comment: What do you see in network requests? Does any request go to your Geoserver?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found seems Apache(geoserver) not allow? Thats my http request : http://localhost:8081/geoserver/data_nl/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=cite%3Avnm_polbnda_adm3_2014_pdc&styles=&format=image%2Fjpeg&transparent=false&version=1.1.1&upperCase=false&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=2504688.5428486555,5009377.085697314,5009377.085697311,7514065.628545967

Comment: Request looks OK, so this seems to be Geoserver problem. Here I can't help you since this is not my area.